# Difference between Option(value) and Some(value)

Tags: scala

I am new to scala !

My question is, if there is case class that contains a member

```
myItem:Option[String]
```

When i construct the class, i need to wrap the string content in:

```
Option("some string")
```

OR

```
Some("some string")
```

Is there any difference ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you look into [Scala's sources](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L25) you'll notice that `Option(x)` just evaluates `x` and returns `Some(x)` on not-null input, and `None` on `null` input.

I'd use `Option(x)` when I'm not sure whether `x` can be `null` or not, and `Some(x)` when 100% sure `x` is not `null`.

One more thing to consider is when you want to create an optional value, `Some(x)` produces more code because you have to explicitly point the value's type:

```
val x: Option[String] = Some("asdasd")
//val x = Option("asdasd") // this is the same and shorter
```

Answer (score 16):

`Option(x)` is basically just saying `if (x != null) Some(x) else None`

See [line 25 of the Source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L25):

```
def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)
```

Comment: It is basically cooler to read `Option("whatever")` looks nicer than `Some("whatever")`. That is why I use it. Hope my lead engineer doesn't read this