# Scala Some v. Option

Tags: scala

What's the difference between `Some` and `Option`?

```
scala> Some(true)
res2: Some[Boolean] = Some(true)

scala> val x: Option[Boolean] = Some(true)
x: Option[Boolean] = Some(true)

scala> res2 == x
res3: Boolean = true
```

I see that `Option(null)` returns, whereas `Some(null)` won't compile:

```
scala> val x = Option(null)
x: Option[Null] = None

scala> val x: Option[Boolean] = Some(null)
<console>:7: error: an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
       val x: Option[Boolean] = Some(null)
                                     ^
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Option(value) and Some(value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908662/difference-between-optionvalue-and-somevalue)

Comment: Not a dupe. But related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/27611133/1296806  Maybe a narrower title is needed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, `Some` extends `Option`, so it inherits everything except `get` and `isEmpty` (and some other methods implemented by a case class).

The companion object of `Option` has a special `apply` method for dealing with `null`:

```
def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)
```

But `Some.apply` is just the standard `apply` method generated for a case class.

`Some(null)` *will* compile in some circumstances, but it has type `Some[Null]` (or `Option[Null]`), which can only be assigned when the type argument of `Option` is a reference type.

```
scala> val a = Some(null)
a: Some[Null] = Some(null)

scala> val b: Option[String] = Some(null)
b: Option[String] = Some(null)
```

You're trying to assign a `Some[Null]` to an `Option[Boolean]`, but a `Null` is not a sub-type of `Boolean`, because `Boolean` is a value type (primitive underneath) and cannot hold a value of `null`.

Comment: Yesterday's question about intersection of boxed primitives and null: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27611133/1296806  You might tell us why `null.asInstanceOf[Int]` is zero (by the spec) but the expected boxed type turns it into null instead of boxed zero. Alternatively, `Some(null) map (runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt)` is zero.

Answer (score 36):

In short

```
           Option
            /   \
           /     \
          /       \
        Some     None
```

Option is container base which can be empty or full

While Some(x) represent full with 'x' being present in the container, None represents empty.

Answer (score 19):

From the functional programming perspective, given an arbitrary type T,  the type Option[T] is an algebraic datatype with data constructors None and Some(x:T).
This is merely a coded way of saying that, if the type T consists of values t1, t2, t3, ... 
then *all* the values of the type Option[T] are None, Some(t1), Some(t2), Some(t3), ...

Most everything else follows from this.  E.g., if null is not a value of T, then Some(null) is not a value of Option[T]. This explains why

```
val x: Option[Boolean] = Some(null)
```

does not work, while

```
val x: Option[Null] = Some(null)
```

does.

Finally, specifically to Scala, there seems to be an additional quirk in that, "for convenience" one may say Option(null) when they mean None. I'd expect one can also say Option(t) when they mean Some(t).

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea of Option is to eliminate using Null in order have a default value and avoid a NullPointerException. So Option can have Some value or None (replacing Null). Check out this great explanation of Option:
[Scala Option explained](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this into English :)